# live/quick mysql query builder/viewer

Tags: php, mysql

Is there such a thing that will allow you to create a mysql query and view its results live? Almost like an ajax sort of live search results kind of thing, so each character i type in will affect my result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of all the **MySQL AJAX clients** I know:

- [SQL Buddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/) ([Screens](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/screenshots/))
- [MonoQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/monoql) ([Demo](http://demo.monoql.com/))
- [TurboDBAdmin](http://www.turboajax.com/) (Offline?)

I'm not sure if they provide real-time response, but they are a faster alternative to [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't be very practical as nearly every other keypress would raise errors against MySQL for syntax issues. I'd just suggest you get [Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/index.html), and hit "Execute" when you're ready to see results.

Comment: Such a system could only query the DB upon insertion of a delimiter such as `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only what you type will just be a part of the query.

You write javascript to fire off an ajax query for each character typed (check out xajax) then your PHP server will make a query using the key you are typing and send back a results update.